# How to limit the text returned from making a TEXT_DETECTION call to Google Vision?

Tags: ios, google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-cloud-vision

I am currently experimenting with levaraging Google Vision API for OCR. When I upload a image, I see the resulting JSON payload returned to me is rather large. I see two major buckets in the response:
1) "textAnnotations"
2) "fullTextAnnotation"

I am only interested in the JSON returned by "textAnnotations" and I dont care about the fullTextAnnotation bucket. Essentially I am only interested in the individual words and their corresponding bounding boxes, I dont need any more granular OCR data. The response seems to parse out paragraphs, symbols, and individual characters as well but I dont need ANY OF THAT.

Is there anyway to filter google vision's result set by sending some flag or parameter in the request? Surely there must be because this JSON being returned is very large.

Comment: Hello @aybaybay , did you manage to find a solution to the problem? Thanks

Comment: Would it be possible to break up the "response" part into more atomic functions that can be reading it as it's returned?  Then you could break from that function when you get to fullTextAnnotation.  I have a similar problem, but at least using the Python Requests library it seems to be one blocking atomic request-response call.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to filter when making the request call.
However, after you get the complete JSON back from Google Vision API request, you would need to have your program work/process just on the "textAnnotations" object

If on Java, you would need to do something like below -
I realized you did tag this with 'iOS', but I am not too familiar with Swift.. But the pseudo-code would be pretty much the same-

1) Parse the JSON using a JSON parser (Eg- JSON.simple / GSON / Jackson / etc)

2) Convert your 'textAnnotations' to a POJO (Plain old Java object)

3) And then in your code, use nested for-loop(s) to cycle through the 'textAnotations' blocks to extract the 'description' element, which is basically what is the OCR'ed word. Reason for nested loops is because "responses", "textAnnotations" are array objects when returned by Google Vision API

```
for (int i = 0; i < size of 'responses' object ; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < size of 'textAnnotations' object; j++) {
              for (int k = 0; k < count of objects ; k++) { 
         System.out.println("OCR Word extracted from Google Vision API JSON - " + (k+1) + " : " + responses[i].textAnnotations[j].description[k])
                }
        }
}
```